# Prove that $\{a,b,c\} \subseteq \{1,4\}$

Tags: number-theory

> Prove that if $$a^n+b^n+c^n \equiv \alpha +\beta \cdot 4^n \pmod{p}$$ for all positive integers $n$, some prime $p>2$, and positive integers $a,b,c$ where $\alpha,\beta$ are constants, then $\{a,b,c\} \subseteq \{1,4\}$  taken modulo $p$.

**Attempt:**
Note: $t_n \equiv \alpha +\beta \cdot 4^n \pmod p$ and all equivalences here are taken modulo $p$.

Using the geometric series we get $$\frac{1}{1-az} + \frac 1{1-bz} + \frac 1{1-cz} = \sum_{n\ge 0}t_nz^n = \frac{\alpha}{1-z} + \frac{\beta}{1-4z}.$$ Now the LHS is $$\dfrac{(1-bz)(1-cz)+(1-az)(1-cz)+(1-az)(1-bz)}{(1-az)(1-bz)(1-cz)}$$ while the RHS is $$\dfrac{\alpha(1-4z)+\beta(1-z)}{(1-z)(1-4z)}.$$ I think some argument about the degree of the denominator might work.

**Context:**

I was originally solving this question.

> Let $a$, $b$, $c$ be positive integers and $p$ be a prime number. Assume that $$a^n(b+c)+b^n(a+c)+c^n(a+b)\equiv 8\pmod{p}$$ for each nonnegative integer $n$. Let $m$ be the remainder when $a^p+b^p+c^p$ is divided by $p$, and $k$ the remainder when $m^p$ is divided by $p^4$. Find the maximum possible value of $k$.

*Solution:*
Assume that $p$ is odd and let $t_n \equiv a^n+b^n+c^n \pmod p$. Plugging in $n=0$ and $n=1$ into the given congruence gives us $$a+b+c \equiv ab+bc+ca \equiv 4 \pmod p.$$ We also see that the given congruence is equivalent to $t_{n+1} \equiv 4t_n-8 \pmod p$ since $$a^n(b+c)+b^n(a+c)+c^n(a+b) =(a+b+c)\left(a^n+b^n+c^n\right) - a^{n+1}-b^{n+1}-c^{n+1}\equiv 8\pmod p.$$ Then, by shifting the index we obtain $t_n \equiv 4t_{n-1}-8 \pmod p$ and subtracting it from the original we get $t_{n+1}\equiv 5t_n-4t_{n-1} \pmod p$. This implies that $t_n \equiv \alpha+\beta \cdot 4^n \pmod p$.

**Lemma 1.** *We have that $a,b,c \not \equiv 0 \pmod{p}$.*

*Proof.* Firstly, we have \begin{align*}
(ab+bc+ca)t_n &= abc \cdot t_{n-1} + \sum_{\text{sym}} a^{n+1}b \\
&\equiv abc\cdot t_{n-1} + 8 \pmod p \\
t_n &\equiv \frac14 abc\cdot t_{n-1} + 2 \pmod p. \\
\end{align*}
Thus, letting $n=2$ and since $S_2 \equiv 8 \pmod p$ we obtain \begin{align*}
8 &\equiv \frac14 abc \cdot 4 + 2 \pmod p \\
abc &\equiv 6 \pmod p. 
\end{align*}
Therefore $a,b,c$ are not equal to $0$ modulo $p$.

**Lemma 2.** *We have that $\{a,b,c\} \subseteq \{1,4\}$.*

This is where my question comes in.

Comment: So, where's the problem from?

Comment: @WillJagy I was solving a question and need to prove this as a lemma.

Comment: Let's try again. What evidence do you have that this is likely to be true?

Comment: @WillJagy It gives the right result to get the correct answer to the question.

Answer (score 0):

I did an actual check for primes bigger than $3,$ always worked. It is a finite check. Worth attempting a genuine proof. Note that it is also possible to have $a \equiv b \equiv c \equiv \alpha \equiv \beta \equiv 0 \pmod p.$ I told the program to have $a,b,c$ nonzero $\pmod p.$

```
jagy@phobeusjunior:~$ 
prime  5           a  1  b  1  c  1  alpha  3  beta  0
prime  5           a  1  b  1  c  4  alpha  2  beta  1
prime  5           a  1  b  4  c  4  alpha  1  beta  2
prime  5           a  4  b  4  c  4  alpha  0  beta  3

prime  7           a  1  b  1  c  1  alpha  3  beta  0
prime  7           a  1  b  1  c  4  alpha  2  beta  1
prime  7           a  1  b  4  c  4  alpha  1  beta  2
prime  7           a  4  b  4  c  4  alpha  0  beta  3

prime  11           a  1  b  1  c  1  alpha  3  beta  0
prime  11           a  1  b  1  c  4  alpha  2  beta  1
prime  11           a  1  b  4  c  4  alpha  1  beta  2
prime  11           a  4  b  4  c  4  alpha  0  beta  3

prime  13           a  1  b  1  c  1  alpha  3  beta  0
prime  13           a  1  b  1  c  4  alpha  2  beta  1
prime  13           a  1  b  4  c  4  alpha  1  beta  2
prime  13           a  4  b  4  c  4  alpha  0  beta  3

prime  17           a  1  b  1  c  1  alpha  3  beta  0
prime  17           a  1  b  1  c  4  alpha  2  beta  1
prime  17           a  1  b  4  c  4  alpha  1  beta  2
prime  17           a  4  b  4  c  4  alpha  0  beta  3

prime  19           a  1  b  1  c  1  alpha  3  beta  0
prime  19           a  1  b  1  c  4  alpha  2  beta  1
prime  19           a  1  b  4  c  4  alpha  1  beta  2
prime  19           a  4  b  4  c  4  alpha  0  beta  3

prime  23           a  1  b  1  c  1  alpha  3  beta  0
prime  23           a  1  b  1  c  4  alpha  2  beta  1
prime  23           a  1  b  4  c  4  alpha  1  beta  2
prime  23           a  4  b  4  c  4  alpha  0  beta  3

prime  29           a  1  b  1  c  1  alpha  3  beta  0
prime  29           a  1  b  1  c  4  alpha  2  beta  1
prime  29           a  1  b  4  c  4  alpha  1  beta  2
prime  29           a  4  b  4  c  4  alpha  0  beta  3

prime  31           a  1  b  1  c  1  alpha  3  beta  0
prime  31           a  1  b  1  c  4  alpha  2  beta  1
prime  31           a  1  b  4  c  4  alpha  1  beta  2
prime  31           a  4  b  4  c  4  alpha  0  beta  3

prime  37           a  1  b  1  c  1  alpha  3  beta  0
prime  37           a  1  b  1  c  4  alpha  2  beta  1
prime  37           a  1  b  4  c  4  alpha  1  beta  2
prime  37           a  4  b  4  c  4  alpha  0  beta  3

prime  41           a  1  b  1  c  1  alpha  3  beta  0
prime  41           a  1  b  1  c  4  alpha  2  beta  1
prime  41           a  1  b  4  c  4  alpha  1  beta  2
prime  41           a  4  b  4  c  4  alpha  0  beta  3

prime  43           a  1  b  1  c  1  alpha  3  beta  0
prime  43           a  1  b  1  c  4  alpha  2  beta  1
prime  43           a  1  b  4  c  4  alpha  1  beta  2
prime  43           a  4  b  4  c  4  alpha  0  beta  3

prime  47           a  1  b  1  c  1  alpha  3  beta  0
prime  47           a  1  b  1  c  4  alpha  2  beta  1
prime  47           a  1  b  4  c  4  alpha  1  beta  2
prime  47           a  4  b  4  c  4  alpha  0  beta  3

prime  53           a  1  b  1  c  1  alpha  3  beta  0
prime  53           a  1  b  1  c  4  alpha  2  beta  1
prime  53           a  1  b  4  c  4  alpha  1  beta  2
prime  53           a  4  b  4  c  4  alpha  0  beta  3

prime  59           a  1  b  1  c  1  alpha  3  beta  0
prime  59           a  1  b  1  c  4  alpha  2  beta  1
prime  59           a  1  b  4  c  4  alpha  1  beta  2
prime  59           a  4  b  4  c  4  alpha  0  beta  3

prime  61           a  1  b  1  c  1  alpha  3  beta  0
prime  61           a  1  b  1  c  4  alpha  2  beta  1
prime  61           a  1  b  4  c  4  alpha  1  beta  2
prime  61           a  4  b  4  c  4  alpha  0  beta  3

prime  67           a  1  b  1  c  1  alpha  3  beta  0
prime  67           a  1  b  1  c  4  alpha  2  beta  1
prime  67           a  1  b  4  c  4  alpha  1  beta  2
prime  67           a  4  b  4  c  4  alpha  0  beta  3

prime  71           a  1  b  1  c  1  alpha  3  beta  0
prime  71           a  1  b  1  c  4  alpha  2  beta  1
prime  71           a  1  b  4  c  4  alpha  1  beta  2
prime  71           a  4  b  4  c  4  alpha  0  beta  3

prime  73           a  1  b  1  c  1  alpha  3  beta  0
prime  73           a  1  b  1  c  4  alpha  2  beta  1
prime  73           a  1  b  4  c  4  alpha  1  beta  2
prime  73           a  4  b  4  c  4  alpha  0  beta  3

prime  79           a  1  b  1  c  1  alpha  3  beta  0
prime  79           a  1  b  1  c  4  alpha  2  beta  1
prime  79           a  1  b  4  c  4  alpha  1  beta  2
prime  79           a  4  b  4  c  4  alpha  0  beta  3

prime  83           a  1  b  1  c  1  alpha  3  beta  0
prime  83           a  1  b  1  c  4  alpha  2  beta  1
prime  83           a  1  b  4  c  4  alpha  1  beta  2
prime  83           a  4  b  4  c  4  alpha  0  beta  3

prime  89           a  1  b  1  c  1  alpha  3  beta  0
prime  89           a  1  b  1  c  4  alpha  2  beta  1
prime  89           a  1  b  4  c  4  alpha  1  beta  2
prime  89           a  4  b  4  c  4  alpha  0  beta  3

prime  97           a  1  b  1  c  1  alpha  3  beta  0
prime  97           a  1  b  1  c  4  alpha  2  beta  1
prime  97           a  1  b  4  c  4  alpha  1  beta  2
prime  97           a  4  b  4  c  4  alpha  0  beta  3

prime  101           a  1  b  1  c  1  alpha  3  beta  0
prime  101           a  1  b  1  c  4  alpha  2  beta  1
prime  101           a  1  b  4  c  4  alpha  1  beta  2
prime  101           a  4  b  4  c  4  alpha  0  beta  3

prime  103           a  1  b  1  c  1  alpha  3  beta  0
prime  103           a  1  b  1  c  4  alpha  2  beta  1
prime  103           a  1  b  4  c  4  alpha  1  beta  2
prime  103           a  4  b  4  c  4  alpha  0  beta  3

prime  107           a  1  b  1  c  1  alpha  3  beta  0
prime  107           a  1  b  1  c  4  alpha  2  beta  1
prime  107           a  1  b  4  c  4  alpha  1  beta  2
prime  107           a  4  b  4  c  4  alpha  0  beta  3

prime  109           a  1  b  1  c  1  alpha  3  beta  0
prime  109           a  1  b  1  c  4  alpha  2  beta  1
prime  109           a  1  b  4  c  4  alpha  1  beta  2
prime  109           a  4  b  4  c  4  alpha  0  beta  3

prime  113           a  1  b  1  c  1  alpha  3  beta  0
prime  113           a  1  b  1  c  4  alpha  2  beta  1
prime  113           a  1  b  4  c  4  alpha  1  beta  2
prime  113           a  4  b  4  c  4  alpha  0  beta  3

prime  127           a  1  b  1  c  1  alpha  3  beta  0
prime  127           a  1  b  1  c  4  alpha  2  beta  1
prime  127           a  1  b  4  c  4  alpha  1  beta  2
prime  127           a  4  b  4  c  4  alpha  0  beta  3

prime  131           a  1  b  1  c  1  alpha  3  beta  0
prime  131           a  1  b  1  c  4  alpha  2  beta  1
prime  131           a  1  b  4  c  4  alpha  1  beta  2
prime  131           a  4  b  4  c  4  alpha  0  beta  3

prime  137           a  1  b  1  c  1  alpha  3  beta  0
prime  137           a  1  b  1  c  4  alpha  2  beta  1
prime  137           a  1  b  4  c  4  alpha  1  beta  2
prime  137           a  4  b  4  c  4  alpha  0  beta  3

prime  139           a  1  b  1  c  1  alpha  3  beta  0
prime  139           a  1  b  1  c  4  alpha  2  beta  1
prime  139           a  1  b  4  c  4  alpha  1  beta  2
prime  139           a  4  b  4  c  4  alpha  0  beta  3

prime  149           a  1  b  1  c  1  alpha  3  beta  0
prime  149           a  1  b  1  c  4  alpha  2  beta  1
prime  149           a  1  b  4  c  4  alpha  1  beta  2
prime  149           a  4  b  4  c  4  alpha  0  beta  3

jagy@phobeusjunior:~$
```